# Проблема вывода данных при помощи Python в MySQL, вывод дублируется несколько раз

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, pgadmin4

По идее, код должен выводить 2 результата в таком формате:

[image: Формат вывода]

Но по какой-то причине, результат дублируется несколько раз. Я пробовал разные подходы, но ничего не помогало. Подскажите чем вы пользуетесь в таких ситуациях.

[image: На скриншоте виден весь код]

Так же, вот содержимое таблиц:

[image: Таблица users]

[image: Таблица items]

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port="3306",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    database="itproger"
)

myCur = mydb.cursor()

myCur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'john'")
user = myCur.fetchone()
user_id = user[0]

sql = "SELECT id FROM items WHERE category = %s"
myCur.execute(sql, ('hats',))

res = myCur.fetchall()

arr_items_id = []
for el in res:
    arr_items_id.append(el[0])

for el in arr_items_id:
  sql = 'INSERT INTO orders(user_id, item_id) VALUES(%s, %s)'
  myCur.execute(sql, (user_id, el))

sql = "SELECT users.login, items.title FROM orders JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id JOIN items ON items.id = orders.item_id"
myCur.execute(sql)
orders = myCur.fetchall()

for order in orders:
    print(f"{order[0]} - {order[1]}")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Похоже, с каждым запуском строк становится все больше? Вы этого и хотели?